# Ubuntu: HTTPS not working on Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, nginx, https, webserver

I have use the following to create the SSL certificate.

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/cerf.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/cerf.pem
```

I also have the following nginx config. The http is working fine on port 8002. However, the https is not working at all. The nginx conf and SSL certificate are in the same folder.

```
upstream django {
    server unix:////var/www/dj_test_prj/dj_test_prj/site.bot.sock; # for a file socket
    #server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we will use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8002;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias  /var/www/dj_test_prj/media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /var/www/dj_test_prj/static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/dj_test_prj/dj_test_prj/uwsgi_params.bot; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    server_name .example.com; # substitute your machine IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key cert.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias  /var/www/dj_test_prj/media;  # your Django project  media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias  /var/www/dj_test_prj/static; # your Django project  static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /var/www/dj_test_prj/dj_test_prj/uwsgi_params.bot; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, what is written to nginx error log???
The log MUST be checked first, and should be attached to the question.

As I can see, you've created `cerf.key` and `cerf.crt` files while configured `cert.key` & `cert.crt` - this should result in failing nginx to start. Please show us `sudo nginx -t` output.